# how to mount volumes as non-root on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to create a statefulset that runs zookeper, but I want it to run as non-root (i.e. under the zookeper user).
This is the image used for this:

https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib/blob/master/statefulsets/zookeeper/Dockerfile

This is how I am trying to mount the volumes (Apparently I need a init container according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/906083/how-to-mount-volume-with-specific-uid-in-kubernetes-pod)):

```
      initContainers:
      # Changes username for volumes
      - name: changes-username
        image: busybox
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          chown -R 1000:1000 /var/lib/zookeeper /etc/zookeeper-conf # <<<<--- this returns
          # cannot change ownership, permission denied
          # read-only filesystem.

      containers:
      - name: zookeeper
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        image: my-repo/k8szk:3.4.14
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          zkGenConfig.sh # The script right here requires /var/lib/zookeper to be owned by zookeper user.
                         # Initially zookeeper user does own it as per the dockerfile above,
                         # but when mounting the volume, the directory becomes owned by root
                         # hence the script fails.
        volumeMounts:
        - name: zk-data
          mountPath: /var/lib/zookeeper
        - name: zk-log4j-config
          mountPath: /etc/zookeeper-conf
```

I also tried to add the securityContext: `fsGroup: 1000` with no change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be configured using the [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods), e.g.

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 1000
  runAsGroup: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
```

Then you don't need the initContainer at all - Kubernetes will handle the recursive chown as part of making the volume ready.

One issue here is the Dockerfile linked doesn't container a `USER` statement, so Kubernetes doesn't know to start the pod as the correct user - the `runAsUser` will fix that.

The reason the `initContainer` hack you're trying isn't working is because you're also trying to change the ownership of the read-only config directory. ConfigMaps are mounted read-only, you can't chown them. (This used to be different, but was changed for security reasons)

Comment: Do you know how to still has sudo privileges inside container after setup securityContext?